# Can't assign object's properties inside the subscribe() function in Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx

I defined the object `persnel` of type `prsnlStateInterface` and trying to assign the properties by subscription to an observable fails. Here is the `persnels` definition:

```typescript
 persnels : prsnlStateInterface = {
    id :'',
    firstname:'',
    lastname : '',
    fullname :'',
    profession : '',
    dob : '',
    nationality: '',
    createdDate: '',
    sex: '',
    gender :'',
    phone :0,
    adresse : '',
    prsnlRoleIds : [0],
    total :0,
    selectedUserId :0,
    ids :[] ,
    entities :{},
  }
```

Here is the the `prsnlStateInterface`:

```typescript
export interface prsnlStateInterface {
    "id": String,
    "firstname": String,
    "lastname": String,
    "fullname": String,
    "profession": String,
    "dob": String,
    "nationality": String,
    "createdDate": String,
    "sex": String,
    "gender": String,
    "phone": number,
    "adresse": String,
    "prsnlRoleIds": [number],
    "total": number,
    "selectedUserId":number,
    "ids":[], 
    "entities":{}
}
```

And this is how I subscribe to the promise:

```typescript
return this.persnlService.getPersnl(data)
    .pipe(
      map((response) => response)
    ).subscribe((obj) => {
    for (const prsnl of Object.values(obj)[2]) {
      console.log('ids', prsnl.id);
      this.persnels = {
        id : prsnl.id,
        firstname: prsnl.id,
        lastname : prsnl.firstname,
        fullname: prsnl.fullname,
        profession: prsnl.function,
        dob: prsnl.dob,
        nationality: prsnl.nationality,
        createdDate: prsnl.createdDate,
        sex: prsnl.sex,
        gender: prsnl.gender,
        phone: prsnl.phone,
        adresse: prsnl.adresse,
        prsnlRoleIds: prsnl.prsnlRoleIds,
        total: 10,
        selectedUserId:0,
        ids:[] ,
        entities:{},
      };
    }; this.store.dispatch(loadPrsnls({this.persnels}));
  })
```

The problem is that Visual Studio is complaining about the `{this.persnels}` when trying to dispatch the data inside NgRx store with `this.store.dispatch(loadPrsnls({this.persnels}))`. It says:

```typescript
Argument of type '{ this: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of
type '{ prsnls: prsnlStateInterface[]; }'.
   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'this' does not exist in type '{ prsnls: prsnlStateInterface[]; }
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

What I don't understand is that I've not defined `persnels` of type any, but of type `prsnlStateInterface`. Moreover, when I replaced `this.store.dispatch(loadPrsnls({this.persnels}))` by `console.log('persnl', this.persnels)` the project compiles but in the console the prsnels properties are undefined.

What am I missing here and how to get it right?

Comment: Are you trying to describe _personnel_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm setting persnels' values inside the subscribe function. What's wrong whith the question?

Comment: I'm trying to clarify your _code_, to start with - are `prsnl `, `persnel`, `personels` all supposed to be the same thing? I don't think a [mre] requires any RxJS or NgRx - what do you think `{this.personels}` is?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's {this.persnels} and not {this.personels}, it's edited.

Comment: My point is more that the inconsistency and txt spk makes the code hard to follow - even if that's acceptable where you're working, it's not OK to post code like this when soliciting help. And this is still nothing to do with Angular, NgRx, RxJS, ... - here's an actual MRE: https://tsplay.dev/WzO6Qw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign `this.prsnls` to a property.
Without knowing how the action is typed, try the following (or something similar):

```
//                                assign the value to the `persnels` property
this.store.dispatch(loadPrsnls({ persnels: this.persnels}))
```

Comment: I was also having interfaces type issues. I had to define in the component.ts persnels as  persnels : prsnlStateInterface[] = [], then declare data as data : prsnlStateInterface{} and then use this.persnels.push(data) to pass objects data inside the persnels array of objects. And ultimately I had also to dispatch persnels as you said. This why I marked your answer as correct answer.